# Hide toolbar component when it isn't on the top of the page

Tags: css, angular, typescript, scroll

I have a toolbar like this[image] 
Its background is transparent. But when i scroll down, this look like [image] 
How can i hide this component when the page scroll down and show it when scroll up to the top of the page?
My English is not good. Sorry about this.

EDIT : 
I use mat-toolbar

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">

<button mat-button routerLink="/" [ngStyle]="{'color': colorStyle === 'WHITE' ? 'white' : 'black'}">
<mat-icon>home</mat-icon> 
{{ 'PAGE.HOME' | translate}}</button>

<!-- This fills the remaining space of the current row -->
<span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
<div fxLayout="row" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm [ngStyle]="{'color': colorStyle === 'WHITE' ? 'white' : 'black'}">
    <button mat-button routerLink="['/home']">{{ 'PAGE.HOME' | translate}}</button>
    <button mat-button routerLink="['/home']">{{ 'PAGE.D9' | translate}}</button>
    <button mat-button routerLink="['/home']">{{ 'PAGE.DThuDuc' | translate}}</button>
    <button mat-button routerLink="['/home']">{{ 'PAGE.MORE' | translate}}</button>
    <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/add']">{{ 'PAGE.ADD' | translate}}</button>
    <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/login']" *ngIf="!loginStatus">{{ 'PAGE.LOGIN' | translate}}</button>
    <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/login']" *ngIf="loginStatus">{{ 'PAGE.LOGOUT' | translate}}</button>
    <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/show-map']" [queryParams]="{ lat: data.lat, lng: data.lng}">{{ 'PAGE.OVERVIEW' | translate}}</button>



</div>
<button mat-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="menu" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm>
 <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
</button>

</mat-toolbar>

.mat-toolbar {

    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: the header looks used` position:fixed` to implement it, would you create an online example let us know how do you implement it?

Comment: https://rent-deploy.herokuapp.com/ , you can see my app here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you use a @HostListener window:scroll

```
  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    let number = window.pageYOffset || 0;
    console.log(number);
  }
```

Some authors consider a bad practice reference a window directy. Brian Love propouse a "window-provider": see http://brianflove.com/2018/01/11/angular-window-provider/

The Brian Love propouse solution:

****It's a Copy and Paste of the referenced article ********

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from "@angular/common";
import { ClassProvider, FactoryProvider, InjectionToken, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

/* Create a new injection token for injecting the window into a component. */
export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken('WindowToken');

/* Define abstract class for obtaining reference to the global window object. */
export abstract class WindowRef {

  get nativeWindow(): Window | Object {
    throw new Error('Not implemented.');
  }

}

/* Define class that implements the abstract class and returns the native window object. */
export class BrowserWindowRef extends WindowRef {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  get nativeWindow(): Window | Object {
    return window;
  }

}

/* Create an factory function that returns the native window object. */
export function windowFactory(browserWindowRef: BrowserWindowRef, platformId: Object): Window | Object {
  if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
    return browserWindowRef.nativeWindow;
  }
  return new Object();
}

/* Create a injectable provider for the WindowRef token that uses the BrowserWindowRef class. */
const browserWindowProvider: ClassProvider = {
  provide: WindowRef,
  useClass: BrowserWindowRef
};

/* Create an injectable provider that uses the windowFactory function for returning the native window object. */
const windowProvider: FactoryProvider = {
  provide: WINDOW,
  useFactory: windowFactory,
  deps: [ WindowRef, PLATFORM_ID ]
};

/* Create an array of providers. */
export const WINDOW_PROVIDERS = [
  browserWindowProvider,
  windowProvider
];
```

In constructor of the component

```
constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window)
```

In Module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [..]
  imports: [..]
  providers: [WINDOW_PROVIDERS,...],
})
```

Comment: sorry, I don't understand why use window provider can avoid reference to the window object directly, it looks different reference in Universal or testing, but in Browser it's same, can you explain more detail?

Answer (score 0):

In style add 
Position:fixed;
z-index:1000;
 give the style to main div of the header.

Answer (score 0):

use `(window:scroll)="eventToBeCalled()"` in the body tag

assign an id to toolbar: 
`<mat-toolbar color="primary" id="matTB">`

and in typescript

```
eventToBeCalled(): void {
   const matToolBar = document.getElementById('matTB');
   if(window.scrollY > 104)
   {
    matToolBar.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
   } else {
    matToolBar.removeAttribute('style');
   }
}
```